# How can I call send_data and send_file from other classes (outside of controller)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I call send_data and **send_file** from other classes (outside of controller)?

For example in my index **controller**, I have send_file and/or send_data. I would like to call them from my own special class.

I have some codes in this class and would like to *continue in same method without exposing anything.*

Sample:

**app/controller/index_controller.rb:**

```
...
def index
   t = TestClass.new
   t.do_something
end
...
```

**app/package/test_class.rb**

```
class TestClass
   def do_something
      send_file params... # GIVES ERROR BECAUSE THIS IS NOT A RAILS CONTROLLER.
   end
end
```

Is there any way to call send_file/send_data from this class? Any way to pass this method? If possible, how? If possible but not recommended, again why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible, but not recommended. Why? Because `send_data` and `send_file` are the **reasons** why controllers even exist! It is [part of] their purpose: parsing input and generating response.

#### But what if I insist?

The simplest thing would be to inject reference to controller into your class. Something like this should work.

```
def index
  t = TestClass.new(self)
  t.do_something
end

class TestClass
  attr_reader :controller

  def initialize(controller)
    @controller = controller
  end

  def do_something
    controller.send_file(...)
  end
end
```

Comment: Due to both answers, I will not call it from outside of a controller. So I will expose my objects (only necessary ones) and use them in controller.

Comment: Both answers are OK for me. But this has what I want and plus, answered earlier then other. So I accept this.

Answer (score 3):

While most things are possible in Ruby, you really shouldn't be calling send_file outside of the controller because it undermines the MVC structure of rails. If yous start down this path, you'll confuse anyone who looks at your code, including your future self, and your project could become increasingly un-maintainable.

If you'd like to have a helper method which supplies the data you'd like to send, then does some cleanup, you can achieve it using a block:

```
class TestClass
  def do_something
    #set up params
    yield params
    #clean up or do other work
  end
end

class IndexController < ApplicationController
  def index
    t = TestClass.new
    t.do_something |params|
      send_file params
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Due to both answers, I will not call it from outside of a controller. So I will expose my objects (only necessary ones) and use them in controller.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to respectfully disagree with the 'don't do it' answers.

The Presenter Pattern is all about rendering outside the controller. Sergio Tulentsev's answer (which is consistent with the Presenter Pattern) works well when you're operating in the context of a single request cycle.

Sometimes, you need to operate outside a single request cycle (as mentioned [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/18409) by DHH himself). In such cases, you can use the approach discussed in the linked thread.

I use both frequently.

Comment: Yep, presenters are good. It is one thing, though, to do this because you have presenters and totally different when you throw rendering code in the same pile with some business logic "just because". If it's the latter, then "don't do it" :)

Comment: Also, what kind of presenter pattern did you mean? The one [described here](http://blog.jayfields.com/2007/03/rails-presenter-pattern.html) doesn't do any rendering. That kind of presenter simply extracts presentation-related logic from models, which otherwise would've been more bloated (date/currency formatting and such)

Comment: I agree, @SergioTulentsev. It's almost never good to do something "just because". But, if there's good reason (as you say), then I say "go for it". There's nothing inherently wrong with passing the controller around or even instantiating a new one as needed.

Comment: Ryan Bates has a nice RailsCast on Presenters that do rendering: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QHsq6aFlP0U

Comment: Nah, it's the same kind of presenter. All its "rendering" is reduced to generating tiny bits of markup for separate tags (links, etc.). The full response body is still produced "normally", by implicitly rendering action's view.

Comment: Or maybe I'm misunderstanding something. Anyway, presenter is a useful pattern. :)

Answer (score 1):

I like the approach @eiko lays out as it rightly keeps send_data in the controller but lets complexity live elsewhere. For others wanting to follow this approach but unsure of the specific block implementation (I wasn't, at first), here's what I ended up with. Within the controller:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.pdf do
    exporter = EventRequirementExporter.new(@event_requirement)
    exporter.export_pdf do |data, filename, mime_type|
      send_data data, filename: filename, type: mime_type, disposition: 'attachment'
    end
  end
end
```

And in the EventRequirementExporter:

```
def export_pdf
  pdf_combiner = CombinePDF.new
  # (buncha stuff happens)
  yield pdf_combiner.to_pdf, combined_filename(:pdf), 'application/pdf'
end
```

The operative part is the yield, which populates the relevant variables in the order supplied in the block. HTH someone.